# How do I remove the Blender FLIP Fluids addon demo watermark?

Tags: fluid-simulation

I have recently purchased the FLIP Fluids addon however the demo watermark still remains in my scene. However I have deleted the demo and updated to the version I have purchased. Is there a way to remove the demo watermark from my scene?

Comment: Hi :). It'd be best to contact the addon developers directly.

Comment: As a commercial addon they have a customer support, why not ask them?

Comment: Make sure you've followed the addon installation [instructions](https://github.com/rlguy/Blender-FLIP-Fluids/wiki/Addon-Installation-and-Uninstallation) exactly

Comment: I did not think about contacting them directly. I'll get right on that. Also I have been reading the instructions but I don't know what could have caused this.

Answer (score 3):

The demo watermark of the FLIP Fluids addon is baked directly into the geometry of the simulation meshes. After installing the full version, you will need to re-bake the simulation.

Comment: Thank you... I was insanely worried that would be the case. I think I messaged you directly on the Blender Market. Thanks for getting back to me. Well here goes another bake of 101 frames at Resolution 600. Oh well, anyways thank you so much for answering my question!

Comment: Oof, your poor computer